# Replacing Ribbon.ascx with a custom version [2013]

Tags: 2013, ribbon, branding

I'm working very deeply in SharePoint 2013 branding and I finally figured out what the `<!--SID:02 {Ribbon} -->` snippet actually brings in -- the code from `~/controltemplates/15/Ribbon.ascx` but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to have SharePoint not render that file, but a custom file I created.

I've found several resources that allow you to package a solution that contains some XML that tells SharePoint to render different parts of the ribbon instead of the default ones (such as `PromotedActions`), but I can't find a resource that would give me the code that would let me have SharePoint render my custom `CustomRibbon.ascx` opposed to the default one.

Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?

**Edit**: I don't want to mess with the ribbon itself (the *Browse* and *Page* parts) but rather add another bar on top of that area, between the blue *SharePoint*  bar and the bar that contains the actual ribbon.

Answer (score 2):

You seriously do not want to start messing with the Ribbon in this way.  That critter is like a great white and once you tangle with it, you will bleed for years from places you didn't know existed.  Trust me on this: I have the scars to prove it.  If you need to add or remove things from the ribbon, follow the XML Feature examples on the web or use the object model as both of those are supported and are less likely to cause help desk related blood loss.

If you need something really out of the ordinary then you might look at creating a custom master page that does not include the Ribbon and only use it for the pages you need the custom behavior for.  This can be done either through code or more simply by placing the lists that need this special behavior in their own site and changing the master page for just that site to use your streamlined master on just that page.

Comment: The thing is, I'm not really looking to mess with the _ribbon_. I want to really move the `PromotedActionsDelegate` to the furthest right it can be, and possibly add another `<div>` between the blue part and the grey part. That's all I'm looking to accomplish, but don't want to mess with the master file.

Comment: If you realy brand tour site you should worK with master pages. We brand all our customers' sites to make it public facing and there is no way do not to use master pages when brand a site.

Comment: Andrew, when you work with master pages, the only code you get regarding the ribbon is `<!--SID:02 {Ribbon} -->`. There is nothing else in the master page that dicates how the Ribbon is rendered, just where.

Comment: Based on your updates it *might* be as simple as adding a DIV and your custom container above the DIV containing the Ribbon.  Again, you can get bit this way as I've seen numerous cases where trying to move the ribbon to anywhere else causes endless scrolling/scaling problems.  FWIW, I just ran across this product that might offer an alternative: http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/12/15/sharepoint-office365-ribbon-ui-customization/

Comment: We really wanted it to go inbetween so we'd have a larger persistent header. I've gone ahead and figured out exactly what I need to do in `Ribbon.ascx`, but I just can't figure out how to use a custom file instead of altering the master one. I understand I might be limited to just putting it inside the container for the ribbon and doing it above the ribbon, but then it looks kind of awkward with the site logo underneath. Who knows...

Comment: For the reccord, what is the part above the ribbon called? Should I change my topic to refer to the _Suite Bar_ specifically?

Comment: That would help as that is actually a completely different part of the UI and handled differently.  Here is one approach to that: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/findnavish/archive/2013/02/07/sharepoint-2013-customizing-suite-bar.aspx or this one for probably more information than you actually want - http://www.sharepointjohn.com/sharepoint-2013-adding-links-suite-bar-newsfeed-skydrive-sites-overriding-suitelinksdelegate-delegate-control/

Comment: Thanks Dave, but those are the areas I've already modified. _Ribbon.ascx_ dictates where those delegate controls are placed, so I'm led to believe if I wanted to cleanly change the positions of those delegates while still keeping the ribbon I would need to replace the Ribbon.ascx

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside if it is a good idea or not, I've had some success replacing built-in WebControls by using a SharePoint DelegateControl stapling it to the `AdditionalPageHead` placeholder as described here: https://littletalk.wordpress.com/2010/11/18/create-an-additionalpagehead-control-packed-into-a-feature-in-visual-studio-2010/

Your custom WebControl then needs to contain code to loop through the ASP.NET controls collection recursively and find the Ribbon ASCX control.

Basically something like the pseudo-code below (though it is much simplified for brevity):

First, get the ASP.NET controls of the current page:

```
this.Page.Controls
```

Then find the Ribbon.ascx (either loop recursively or use another smart way to find it deep down the controls collection):

```
if (childControl.ToString().ToLower() == "ribbon.ascx")
```

Note: haven't tried this code snippet myself because I don't have my development VM with me, but it should serve you as an example to get you started.